# mysql inserts an empty date if the date isn't correct

Tags: mysql

Ok,

So I tried inserting the date '2015-02-29' (which doesn't exist, as 2015 is not a leap year) into a mysql date field. Instead of an error of sorts, it simply inserted '0000-00-00' as the date.

Why does it occur? How can I prevent or catch this? How do I have to configure the date column?

Thanks

EDIT:

The data was uploaded as a CSV file and inserted using LOAD DATA INFILE.

We can assume the following query however:

`INSERT INTO TableName ('date') VALUES ('2015-02-09')`

Comment: because you didn't try to insert **date** as you wrote, you did try to insert **string**. so to avoid it try to prepare date and bind it to the request show us code you use to insert. Where this value came from? :-)

Comment: the value was in a CSV file, where the dates are inserted as such: YYYY-MM-DD, every other date in that file inserted correctly. Except the Feb 29-2015

Comment: how do you insert those rows? php?

Comment: if you want, assume the following sql query:  INSERT INTO TableName ('date')  VALUE ('2015-02-29')

Comment: set your table column date `NOT NULL` and when insert `INSERT INTO TableName ('date') VALUE (DATE('2015-02-29')) ` that must bring error

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the `sql_mode` to change the behaviour how MySQL handles the invalid date.

According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html), this happens when you insert an incorrect date value:

> By default, when MySQL encounters a value for a date or time type that
>   is out of range or otherwise invalid for the type, it converts the
>   value to the “zero” value for that type. The exception is that
>   out-of-range TIME values are clipped to the appropriate endpoint of
>   the TIME range.

So a zero value is inserted and you actually get a warning about that. You can see that with the `show warnings` command.

```
insert into TableName (`date`) values ('2015-02-29');
-- 1 row(s) affected
show warnings
-- Warning  1264    Out of range value for column 'date' at row 1
```

You can change this behaviour to store the invalid value, if you need so ([MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html)):

> By setting the SQL mode to the appropriate value, you can specify more
>   exactly what kind of dates you want MySQL to support. (See Section
>   5.1.7, “Server SQL Modes”.) You can get MySQL to accept certain dates, such as '2009-11-31', by enabling the ALLOW_INVALID_DATES SQL mode.
>   This is useful when you want to store a “possibly wrong” value which
>   the user has specified (for example, in a web form) in the database
>   for future processing.

For example, the following should work:

```
set @@sql_mode='allow_invalid_dates';
insert into TableName (`date`) values ('2015-02-29');
-- 1 row(s) affected
```

Or, you can also change the behaviour of [load data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) or insert to report the error:

> Treatment of empty or incorrect field values differs from that just
>   described if the SQL mode is set to a restrictive value. For example,
>   if sql_mode='TRADITIONAL, conversion of an empty value or a value such
>   as 'x' for a numeric column results in an error, not conversion to 0.
>   (With LOCAL, warnings occur rather than errors, even with a
>   restrictive sql_mode value, because the server has no way to stop
>   transmission of the file in the middle of the operation.)

Example:

```
set @@sql_mode='traditional';
insert into TableName (`date`) values ('2015-02-29');
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '2015-02-29' for column 'date' at row 1
```