# Output of Date in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, datagrip

Today I was using datagrip with the new view of MariaDB, and at executing

```
SELECT DATE('2018-03-01');
```

return '2018-02-28'. Meanwhile on MySQL view return the same Date that I put as String version.

I use MariaDB 10.1.26 with XAMP, Datagrip 2018.1. 
It's the first time that make this.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this sounds like an issue relating to timezones, but I'm not familiar enough with MariaDB or Datagrip to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: What TZ is current for DataGrip and for MariaDB instance? What does show variables like ‘time_zone’ show?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`

Answer (score 0):

Try use the [CONVERT_TZ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)  because your problem is probably related to timezone, who are different their two instances (Maria and My), or update the timezone in the instances to be the same.

To check the timezone:

> select @@system_time_zone;

Comment: I tried with @@ system_time_zone, but both (MySQL and MariaDB) return the same value "Standard Time, America Cent", so I doubt it could be caused by it. The conversion of strings to dates worked correctly until today.

Comment: Try run now() function to see the result, please

Comment: 2018-04-05 17:56:54 MySQL, 2018-04-05 17:57:31 MariaDB

Comment: The timezone it's OK, your problem is in MariaDB, lets try check the sql mode from the server. Run this script in both servers: `SELECT @@SQL_MODE, @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE;`. Because I'm asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703885/mysql-inserts-an-empty-date-if-the-date-isnt-correct?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa